# How does Spring session Data + Redis cluster handle sessions?

Tags: java, spring, session, redis

According to the Redis document,
(link : https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/)

**Events in a cluster**

Every node of a Redis cluster generates events about its own subset of the keyspace as described above. However, unlike regular Pub/Sub communication in a cluster, events' notifications are not broadcasted to all nodes. Put differently, keyspace events are node-specific. This means that to receive all keyspace events of a cluster, clients need to subscribe to each of the nodes.

In Redis cluster mode, it is difficult to get a response when the key expires...

but Srping session data handles it.

How does Spring session data handle an expiration of a session?